# python boto route53 - first use

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I'm a bit new to boto, seems nice but I came across some problem.
I'm trying to create some hosted zone from my python script but also using ipython i can't figure out how to add records to my zone

```
conn = boto.route53.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
zone = conn.create_hosted_zone("example.com.")
```

normally I would use

```
status = zone.add_record("MX", "example.com.", "10 mail.isp.com")
```

to add records, but with `create_hosted_zone` I don't have the `add_record` function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to take a look into the [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/route53.html#boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection.create_hosted_zone) and compare `create_zone` and `create_hosted_zone`. `create_hosted_zone` does not return a zone object which would have the `add_record` method. `create_zone` instead returns a zone object and you should be able to add your records.

Comment: I see, so I've to create the hosted zone and then edit it with get_all_rrsets?

Comment: You could just delete `hosted_` from your source and it should work…

Comment: ok thanks. but what is the main difference? why should i use one, rather than another?

Comment: On the one hand I described exactly that in my answer, on the other hand you really should take a look into the documentation I linked for you. There you will see my answer in other words.